# Como podria emitir un sonido en una app de WPF de Visual Studio mediante un controlador?

Tags: c#, wpf

muy buenas, estoy intentando realizar un controlador , concretamente un botón que al pulsar, la interfaz WPF de Visual Studio me emita un sonido simple (como si es formato wav o mp3), sin embargo todo lo que he visto para hacerlo lo realizan en Windows Forms y nadie lo ha hecho en una WPF, no es posible hacerlo o simplemente la gente prefiere hacerlo en el otro. Alguien tiene idea de como se podría hacer en WPF?

Comment: A que te refieres con "controlador"? Reproducir un sonido con la pulsacion de un boton es sencillo, explica un poco mejor que es lo que quieres y si tienes algo de código.

Comment: no tengo código, pues imagínate que tengo un controlador(Button) y con el evento de Button_Click por ejemplo, al pulsar pues me reproduzca un sonido o mas bien agregar un sonido que luego lo pueda reproducir. No se si me he explicado mejor, un saludo

Comment: Pues simplemente añade un control `MediaElement` y en el click del boton dale al ejecutas el metodo `Play` del mismo

Comment: okey perfecto, ahora lo intento , muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrégalo directamente como un trigger en el etiquetado XAML, algo así:

```
<Button Content ="Play">
   <Button.Style>
    <Style>
     <Style.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
       <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <SoundPlayerAction Source="02 Best I Ever Had.wav"></SoundPlayerAction>
       </EventTrigger.Actions>
      </EventTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
   </Button.Style>
  </Button>
```

Necesitarás referenciar el namespace System.Media.SoundPlayer